# how to start/stop an application pool in IIS 6.0 from Java remotely

Tags: java, windows, iis, iis-6

Can I start and stop IIS 6.0 application pools on one machine from within Java code running on another machine? If so, how?

Comment: does java run on IIS? i m curious. if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java's [facility to execute another program](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) and use the command line tool such as

```
appcmd stop apppool /apppool.nam
appcmd start apppool /apppool.nam
```

(see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732742(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I guess with IIS6.0 the command line would be something like this: psexec \\my-machine -u Administrator -p password C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisapp.vbs /a MyAppPool /r

Comment: Hm... passing password on the command line is not nice.  Might want to output that to stdin of the process, I think psexec can take password interactively.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it using WMI. Please take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525309(v=vs.90).aspx

and here: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9041b0a5-c314-46d9-8f56-01506687f357.mspx?mfr=true

Or just google "iis wmi".

First find API you need and find a way to write JScript or VBScript that does what you need.

Then you have 2 ways.

1. Just execute script you have just done from java using `Runtime.exec()`
2. Use one of interoparability packages like JaWin, JIntegra or JInterop (or, probably others) to call the same code from java.